# (#100) link URL is not properly formatted when posting to a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a URL to a facebook page. using PHP SDK.
I am able to post successfully from my localhost. But on the live server, I get the result "Sorry, something went wrong".

when running the code from live server, I have no problem obtaining access_token to post to the page.
Only the posting will not work.

I tried to post the link manually using the graph api explorer. and found that

1. I am ABLE to post a **message** successfully via the graph api explorer.
2. I am NOT able to post a URL via the graph api explorer. I get the error

> **"(#100) link URL is not properly formatted"**
>   
>   I do encode the link that i am trying to post. and they are valid, existing links.

I even tried using http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com , and it would return the same error.

### Some Other information

1. The code is executed from **mydomainname.com/folder/**
2. I have added the domain name to "App Domains" field.
3. Sandbox Mode is On.
4. When I tested from my local, I was able to post 25 links to the
   page.[after which it was giving errors]. When things were not
   working at the live server, I came back to locahost to again test
   with 25 links and more and found things to be working fine from
   localhost. I wonder if I hit some limit or my application has been
   black listed.

Anyone has got any ideas?

Thanks

## UPDATE

I took the URL that was used by the live server (to post link to the facebook page) , and used fiddler to post it from my local machine. and it worked.
so i am wondering whats preventing the code from working successfully from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same code from another domain and it worked.

I am yet to find out if it was not working because of the way the 1st domain was sending CURL requests, or if the domain was blacklisted for posting too much in the past.

either way, facebooks error messages are not at all helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your own wall, notice the difference between:

"me/feed" and "me/photos" url. The first one doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the same thing but unfortunately it works for online images but not for local ones. i.e

```
'picture' => class_exists('CurlFile', false) ? 
             new CURLFile($photo, 'image/jpg') : "@{$photo}",
```

will not work, but

'picture' => "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGWZD.jpg?s=24&g=1",

will work

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with this. Weirdly enough it only worked when I sent the url to the picture **without** any URL encoding via the POST request to the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Try the link without the quotation marks "". I was stuck as you but not any more without the quotation marks.